# Html div, padding

Tags: html, css

This is my assignment and I require you guys to put in your words please.

**If you add border or padding to the div then this border or padding is added to the total size of the div which affects all the other elements. Please elaborate this phenomenon and how do you propose fixing it ?**

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to ask a specific question. Also have a look at [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions#) on how to revise your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use: box-sizing: border-box.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the height and width of any element is calculated like this:

width + padding + margin + border = actual total width
height + padding + margin + border = actual total height

This means that the element often appears bigger than the "width" you set because the element's padding, margin, and border are also added to its width/height.

To counter this, you can use `box-sizing: border-box;` in your CSS. The property includes the element's padding, margin, and border in its total width and height.